# Endomorphism of compact topological group preserving conjugacy classes on dense subset

Tags: group-theory, compactness, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact topological group and $f:G\to G$ a continuous homomorphism. Assume there is a dense subset $X\subset G$, such that that for all $x\in X$, we have that $f(x)$ is conjugate to $x$. Is it then true that $f(g)$ is conjugate to $g$ for all $g\in G$?

If $G$ were a metric space, we could make a sequence argument. Pick some sequence $(x_n)_n \in X$ converging to $g$. Then there are elements $(g_n)_n \in G$ such that

$$f(x_n)=g_nx_ng_n^{-1}. $$
Because $G$ is compact, we can pick a converging subsequence of $(g_n)_n$ with limit $g_0$. Then
$$f(g)=g_0gg_0^{-1}.$$

I am not sure how to adapt this argument to the case where $G$ is not a metric space.

Comment: Why don't you work with nets?

Comment: You should also assume that $G$ is Hausdorff otherwise the claim is false.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, I posted an answer, where I use nets and the proof goes basically the same way. I am using that $G$ is Hausdorff in an essential way. Do you have a counterexample, where $G$ is not Hausdorff?

Comment: Take the trivial topology, and use the fact that $1$ is dense in $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moishe Kohan suggested, one may use nets, if we add the assumption that $G$ is Hausdorff. Fix $g\in G$. For each open $U\subset G$ containing $g$, we may pick am element $x_U \in X \cap U$. We obtain two nets $(x_U)_U \subset X$ and $(g_U)_U \subset G$, such that
$$f(x_U)=g_Ux_Ug_U^{-1}.$$ Using the compactness assumption, we may pass to subsequences and assume that both nets converge. Clearly $(x_U)_U$ converges to $g$. Because $f$ is continuous $(f(x_U))_U$, converges to $f(g)$. Let $g_0$ be the limit of $(g_U)_U$.

$G$ being Hausdorff, implies that limits of nets are unique. If we prove that $(f(x_U))_U$ converges to $g_0gg_0^{-1}$, we may conclude that $f(g)=g_0gg_0^{-1}$.

The function
$$\psi:G^3\longrightarrow G,\psi(g_1,g_2,g_3)=g_1g_2g_3^{-1}$$
is continuous and the limit of the net $(g_U,x_U,g_U)_U \subset G^3$ is $(g_0,g,g_0) \in G^3$. Therefore the limit of $(f(x_U)_U)$ is $g_0gg_0^{-1}$.